# Sprague–Grundy numbers

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

I would appreciate if someone can help me understand the columns of the table in this blog: http://lbv-pc.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/treblecross.html .

The author writes he leaves this as an exercise to the reader and I could not find the answers myself.

Thank you.

Comment: [This is an introduction to the Sprague-Grundy theory](http://blog.plover.com/math/sprague-grundy.html)

Answer (score 0):

The first column, labeled "Game", contains what they call the "clean board" game considered in that row; e.g. "$(5)$" denotes a game on a clean board of size $5$.

The second column, labeled "Reachable"; contains the positions reachable from that clean board; e.g. on a clean board of size $5$, you can place an X in the first slot (from either end), leaving games of size $0$ and $2$, or in the second slot (from either end), leaving games of size $0$ and $1$, or in the middle slot, leaving games of size $0$ on both sides.

The last column, labeled "Nimber", contains the nimber associated with the clean board position in the first column, calculated according to standard nimber arithmetic; e.g. for the clean board of size $5$, first form the XOR of the values of all three pairs of games reachable (as described above). Since those games are always smaller than the game under consideration, you can proceed recursively by filling in the table from top to bottom. So if you've filled it up to the row for game $(5)$, you know that $(0)$, $(1)$ and $(2)$ have nimbers $0$, $1$ and $1$, respectively, so the three XORs for the three possible moves described above are $0\oplus1=1$, $0\oplus1=1$ and $0\oplus0=0$. Then applying the rule of the minimum excluded (MEX) value, given that $0$ and $1$ are excluded, yields the nimber $2$ for that row.

Comment: Hi,
and thanks a lot for the fast and helpful answer. After reading it and the blog again, it is clearer and I think I got it. 

I have 2 points to discuss:

'Reachable':
- the explanation assumes 'clean board of 5' is 
a game with 5 slots not surrounded by any X  (otherwise numbers in brackets change)
- in game 5 if we place an X in the first slot we technically have only one game, as we have a game of 4 slots, but still it is considered as {(0),(2)} --> is this a mistake? or do we consider it a game of 0 slots and on of 4?

I would appreciate if you write what you think for these 2 points.

Comment: And thanks for mentioning the mex function - they do not mention it on the blog.

Comment: @MichaelMichael: I'm not sure what your two points are -- I only see one. It doesn't make a difference in the result whether you consider the games of size $0$ as lost games or non-existent games, since their nimber $0$ is the identity element of the XOR operation, i.e. XORing with $0$ doesn't change the result. I think they just included them to make the whole thing more regular and thus easier to follow, with each game splitting into exactly two games.

Comment: Regarding the MEX: It says "For those who are not yet familiar with these topics I can highly recommend the following article that does an excellent job explaining the basics of it: [Sprague–Grundy theory](http://blog.plover.com/math/sprague-grundy.html)." and that page explains the MEX.

Comment: yes, that makes sense , I also had the feeling they included them to make it easier to follow, just that they did not mention it explicitly.  The first point was if we assume or not that the clean board of game 5 is surrounded by no X , as I think if it was a game of 6 with X on slot 1 or a game of 7 with X-es on slot 1 and 7 things would change.   Thanks again for the answers.  I do not have the ability to rank your post , as I would have done it :)

Comment: @MichaelMichael: I see; that wasn't formulated as a question in your first comment :-). Yes, the "clean board" is just that board, not surrounded by Xs, and yes, the other cases you describe would be different. This is the reason for the slightly inelegant prescription "$\max(0,L-2x)$, where $x$ is the number of X’s that surround the open interval" -- in the last paragraph, they redo it properly by extending the board with extra space and terminating Xs; that eliminates the special cases and makes it easier to think about (to my mind).

Comment: @MichaelMichael: As regards "ranking my post": There's no need to upvote it if you can't; just mark it as the accepted answer if it's fully answered your question -- not just to give me points but mainly so the question no longer appears as "unanswered" (and thus draws attention away from actually unanswered questions). (You can do that by clicking on the checkmark at the top left of the answer to toggle it from gray to green.)